# Automatically submit form at a fixed time in a day

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to submit a form at 11.30 am and 8.30 pm automatically in a single day.

This is the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
```

I need the solution through `jquery`.

Comment: Please show us some researches you have tried before asking here, or some code logic.

Comment: I've attempted to answer your question, please take a look if it fits your needs.

Comment: Firstly its a webpage you need to keep that webpage active whole day and have to calculate current time at regular intervals... I don't understand why do you have to it at first place I have never seen something like this before if in case you find a solution please comment or post answer Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
 window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  // Check time and update the button's state every second.
  setInterval(updateSubmitButton, 1000);
}, false);

function updateSubmitButton() {
var currentTime = new Date();
var hours = currentTime.getHours();
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();

// at 11.30 am and at 8.30 pm

if ((hours === 11 && minutes === 30) 
|| (hours === 20 && minutes === 30)) {
document.getElementById('submit').click();
} else {
console.log( "Wait for specified time" );
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date();

var hours = date.getHours();

var minutes = date.getMinutes();

if( hours === 20 && minutes === 30 || hours === 23 && minutes === 30 ) {

    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();

}
else {

    console.log( "Not yet time" );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

same as :

```js
var date = new Date();
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var count_minutes = hours*60 + minutes;
var time_out = 0;
var time_interval = 0;
// 690  = 11h 30 am
// 1230 = 8h 30 pm
if (count_minutes <= 690) {
    time_out = 690 - count_minutes;
    // 540 = 9h from 11h 30 am to 8h 30 pm
    time_interval = 540;
}
else if (690 < count_minutes <= 1230) {
    time_out = 1230 - count_minutes;
    // 900 = 15h from 8h 30 pm to 11h 30 am
    time_interval = 900;
}
else {
    time_out = (24*60 - count_minutes) + 510;
    time_interval = 540;
}
setTimeOut(function(){
    submitForm();
    setInterval(function(){
        submitForm();
    }, 24*60*60*1000);
    setInterval(function(){
        submitForm();
    }, time_interval*60*1000);
},time_out*60*1000);

function submitForm () {
    // code submit 
    // $('#submit').trigger('click');
}
```